# Can I put a proper smiley, or image, into a page using Greasemonkey and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, greasemonkey

I am putting together a script with a smiley. I do not have an option to use a web server to upload smiley as a .png.
How can I make the position of smiley in the right direction?

```
$("#breadcrumbContainer").append("<span class='rcs1' style='float:right;cursor:pointer;margin-right:5px;background-color:lime'>:-)</span>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the plain ASCII `:-)` in a rotated block element:

```js
$("#breadcrumbContainer").append(
     '<div style="transform: rotate(0.25turn); width:1em; height:1em">:-)</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="breadcrumbContainer">Test</div>
```

To make it more universal place the CSS style into a separate block (you may use [GM_addStyle](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) function) and add vendor aliases for the experimental `transform` property: `-webkit-transform`,
`-moz-transform` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode provides a smiley face that points in the right direction

U+236A is "☺"

You can also use a "kaomoji" if you want to get fancy, for example:

- (⌒▽⌒)☆
- (*^▽^*)
- (★^O^★)
- ｡◕‿◕｡
- (◑‿◐)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add [Font-Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to your project and you just have to do:

```
$("#breadcrumbContainer").append('<i class="fa fa-smile-o"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try **Webdings** and **Wingdings** font to use smiley. It contains so many images to use with web. (Or you may use unicode) Below is a screenshot;

[image: Wingdings]

Along with this, there is a simple solution for you. Upload your images to image hosting services like **[imgur](http://imgur.com)** (the one stackoverflow uses), and you can get a direct link to your images like https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaReM.png . Use this url to place images in your webpage.

You may also take a look at;

**[HTML Decimal Code & Unicode Hexadecimal Code for iOS and Safari Emoticons](http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php)**

and

**[Emoji Unicode Tables](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-3-transport-and-map-symbols)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proper smiley, **or any image you like and you don't need a server** to do it.

Use [`GM_getResourceURL`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceURL).  The only trick is to save the image you want in the same folder as the `*.user.js` file, before you install it. (Or even after, if you savvy Firefox profile folders.)

For example:

1. Save this code as `InsImage.user.js`:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name        _Insert any smiley, or any image using Greasemonkey
   // @match       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
   // @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
   // @resource    mySmiley Pn708.png
   // @grant       GM_getResourceURL
   // ==/UserScript==

   $('<img>').appendTo ("#question-header > h1 > a.question-hyperlink")
   .attr ('src', GM_getResourceURL ("mySmiley") )
   ;
   ```

   Put it in some folder that is convenient to you.
2. Now download this image to the same folder:
   `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn708.png`   ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn708.png))
3. Open that folder and drag and drop `InsImage.user.js` onto Firefox (Or Chrome with Tampermonkey installed).
4. Follow the prompts to install the script.  The image will be automatically copied over.
5. Success!